# receive an system.object variable from SSIS and loop on it in foreach parallel loop in C#

Tags: c#, ssis

Ths code as it appears works fine but here i insert by Add. all the values into the listTables. While what I want is to assing an object variable (User::Hosps) from SSIS (system.object) to the list (or to an array)
How can it be done?
This part:

```
OleDbDataAdapter A = new OleDbDataAdapter();
     System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
     A.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::Hosps"].Value);
```

is something i found online and tryed to use but the values it assigns to the list are not the values i want from the object.

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types; 
#endregion

namespace ST_ef6fc7b20ff94cbfb2587ed23a6520a0
{

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        public void Main()
        {
         OleDbDataAdapter A = new OleDbDataAdapter();
         System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
         A.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::Hosps"].Value);

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
             Tables.Add(row.ToString());
        }


          List<string> Tables = new List<string>();
             Tables.Add("ABRAVIV");
             Tables.Add("FLIMANAVIV");
             Tables.Add("BSHAVIV");
             Tables.Add("LEVAVIV");
             Tables.Add("BEERAVIV");
             Tables.Add("TIRAAVIV");
             Tables.Add("SHRAVIV");
             Tables.Add("MAZAVIV");
             Tables.Add("NTNYAAVIV");
             Tables.Add("SHMUELAVIV");
             Tables.Add("PARDESAVIV");
             Tables.Add("RISHONAVIV");

        Parallel.ForEach(Tables, Table =>
        {

             SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
                          myConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=vmbi-devdb\\gp;Initial Catalog=GP;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=false;";
             SqlDataReader rdr = null;
             myConnection.Open();
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("exec Mirror_Logistic.Load_Table_From_Source " + Table, myConnection);
             cmd.CommandTimeout = 0; 
             rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             myConnection.Close();         


           });
            }
     #region ScriptResults declaration
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Actually the variable User::Hosps contains the same values i assigned with the Tables.Add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, you got me confused.

Do you want to assign the values from ur SSIS-Object to a list?
Or do you want to assign ur values from C# to your object?

```
    public void Main()
    {
     OleDbDataAdapter A = new OleDbDataAdapter();
     System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
     A.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::Hosps"].Value);  List<string> myValues = new list<string>();

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
         myValues.Add(row[0].ToString());
    }
```

Comment: As far as i can see, your doing it correct. You can only ADD your SSIS-Object to the list, by using a datatable and using foreach. So the correct method is using Add :)

Comment: The first option :assign the values from  SSIS-Object variable to a list

Comment: Okay, then your doing it correct. Just removed your manually added rows :)